# How is the sample space the same in the given binomial distribution?

Tags: probability, statistics, problem-solving, binomial-distribution

In the following video lecture of Prof. Blitzstein, Probability, we have the following:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k2BB0p8byGA

time stamp: 22:20-22-40 (20 seconds)

**If you don't wish to watch the video, my doubt is as follows:**

Respected Prof. Blitzstein says that given two random variables binomially distributed -- X Bin(n,p) and Y Bin(m,p). Then X+Y makes "sense" because the sample space of both are the same. However, the sample space of X consists only those sequences of successes and failures that are of length '**n**', and the the sample space of Y consists only those sequences of successes and failures that are of length '**m**'.

So, how can the sample spaces of both X and Y possibly be the same?

Comment: That is not quite what he is saying.  Instead he is saying that as random variables, each of $X$ and $Y$ is a function from a sample space (here to the non-negative integers).  He is then saying that $X+Y$ is meaningful as the sum of functions  if $X$ and $Y$ are functions from the same sample space.  In effect he is saying  for each element of the joint sample space $\omega \in \Omega$ you have    $(X+Y)(\omega)=X(\omega)+Y(\omega)$.

Comment: There are many different values of $\omega$ which give the same value of $X(\omega)$ and you can say similar things for $Y(\omega)$ and for $(X+Y)(\omega)$ as  $\Omega$ can be large and here must be large enough to deal with his specific assumption that $X$ and $Y$ are independent.  In this way, a large sample space does not preclude it from being a sample space for $X$ and at the same time a sample space for $Y$, and therefore also a sample space for $X+Y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The professor is *not* saying that the sample space of $X$ and $Y$ is the same. What he is saying is that if you take a coin that lands on heads with probability $p$, and flip it $n + m$ times, then:

1. The number of heads in the first $n$ flips can be written as $X \sim B(n, p)$
2. The number of heads in the last $m$ flips can be written as $Y \sim B(m, p)$
3. $X$ and $Y$ are independent of each other, since the flips that determine their values do not overlap
4. The number of heads across all the flips can be written as $X + Y \sim B(n + m, p)$ (where the right-hand side comes straight from the fact that there are $n + m$ independent flips, each with probability $p$, and the left-hand side comes from the fact that the total number of heads must be the number of heads in the first $n$ flips plus the number of heads in the last $m$ flips)